# How do I send e-mail from an AT&T residential account with System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

Apologies if this should be on SuperUser, but this appears to be a .NET configuration issue I'm having rather than an issue with my ISP.

I'm trying to send out e-mail using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.  I'm on an AT&T Uverse residential line, so outbound port 25 is completely blocked and the only way to send e-mail is through their approved SMTP server, over port 465, over SSL.  The settings can be found here: https://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB401570&ct=9000812.  When I try to send e-mail using what I assume are the correct settings for SmtpClient, all I get is "System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Here's my code:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.att.yahoo.com";
client.Port = 465;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@bellsouth.net", "password");
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("email@bellsouth.net");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("foo@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "This is the body";

client.Send(message);
```

The exception occurs on the call to client.Send(message).  I've also tried using App.config as follows:

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network
              host="smtp.att.yahoo.com"
              port="465"
              defaultCredentials="false"
               enableSsl="true"
               userName="email@bellsouth.net"
               password="password"
            />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

and just left by C# code as:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();

var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("email@bellsouth.net");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("foo@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "This is the body";

client.Send(message);
```

Are there other settings I should be using?  Has anyone had success in sending e-mail from .NET through `smtp.att.yahoo.com`?  I can say that this does work in Outlook, so it's not like there's some block somewhere.

**EDIT:** Gmail is out because I need to be able to keep the from address dynamic and gmail forces the sender to the account.  i.e. I have a domain and I need to be able to send from @mydomain.com.

Comment: Just curious - what does AT&T offer for e-mail that's worth the hassle?

Comment: I certainly do not go to them for my e-mail needs.  However, in order to be able to send out e-mail (without paying for a relay), I have to use their only path out.

Comment: Why don't you just use Gmail?

Comment: I don't want the FROM: to be limited.

Comment: Have you tried sending email through Telnet? For example: --> http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html

Comment: @Pandincus - the link is not working for me, but if you mean something like "telnet smtpserver.com 25" (or in this case "telnet smtpserver.com 465"), then yes.  There's no response, but I imagine this has something to do with SSL (i.e. you can't have an SMTP conversation manually over SSL).

Comment: @Chris Simmons: Oh, darn. :-( Sorry, I didn't realize that.

Comment: I finally got someone at Uverse support who knew about unblocking port 25.  Unfortunately, they charge a $29 fee, but it's one-time and makes all the nonsense like above go away.  Of course, if anyone has an answer, feel free to post.  I'll check to see if it works for me and mark it correct.  However, this is now a non-issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to send emails through smtp.att.yahoo.com using the non secure port 587:

```
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = false;
```